# The term 'node.exe' is not recognized- [Node JS]

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, web, mern

While trying to create a MERN project, I'm getting an error. My system already has Nodejs installed. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong.

[This is what it shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xEDoO.png)
[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the `PATH` for Node.js. Try to add it in environment variables so it is available in your `PATH`.
If already added, please reopen the command prompt.

[image: Environment variables configuration screen]